# onClientConnectionState() - status=19 clientIf=9

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am developing an application where I have to connect with a glucose service device(accu chek) using bluetooth and fetch the data. I am able to connect with the device but when I am putting the strip inside the glucose meter, the app gets disconnected with the message  :

> onClientConnectionState() - status=19 clientIf=9 device=91:F2:02:97:5F:43

Why is that happening?

Comment: Maybe some internal "no activity" timeout is set ? Can you try reading a characteristic after the connection is established ?

Comment: No, I don't think timeout is the case. The moment I insert the strip, device is disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

Status 19 just means that the device initiated a disconnect. It seems that your device doesn't like to do bluetooth while a strip is inserted for a measurement. Try connecting after a measurement has been taken...